# Power BI average between different dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I want to calculate average time between to dates. The data looks like this:

| Step | Datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 14.11.2022 13:02:56 |
| 4 | 14.11.2022 13:05:15 |
| 2 | 14.11.2022 13:11:23 |
| 4 | 14.11.2022 13:13:38 |
| 2 | 14.11.2022 13:24:03 |
| 4 | 14.11.2022 13:26:21 |
| 2 | 15.11.2022 12:16:58 |
| 4 | 15.11.2022 12:19:28 |

**I need to get an average time between all the steps number 4 and steps number 2.**

14.11.2022 13:05:15 - 14.11.2022 13:02:56 = 00:02:19

14.11.2022 13:13:38 - 14.11.2022 13:11:23 = 00:02:15

14.11.2022 13:26:21 - 14.11.2022 13:24:03 = 00:02:18

15.11.2022 12:19:28 - 15.11.2022 12:16:58 = 00:02:30

The average between all four equals to **00:02:20.**

When I use formula **measure = CALCULATE(SUM(Logging[CreatedAt]),Logging[Step] = 4) - CALCULATE(SUM(Logging[CreatedAt]),Logging[Step] = 2)** it calculates the total of all four rows.

The result of the formula above **30.12.1899 0:09:22.**

(by the way, how to get rid of this strange date result 30.12.1899?)

If I use formula **measure = AVERAGEX(Logging, CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Logging[CreatedAt]), FILTER(Logging, Logging[Step] = 4)) - CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Logging[CreatedAt]), FILTER(Logging, Logging[Step] = 4)))** it delivers nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Avg Time Delta = 
VAR T2 =
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE('Table'[Datetime]),
        'Table'[Step] = 2
    )
VAR T4 = 
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE('Table'[Datetime]),
        'Table'[Step] = 4
    )
VAR Seconds = 
    DATEDIFF(T2, T4, SECOND)
VAR Minutes = 
    INT ( Seconds / 60 )
VAR RemSeconds =
    MOD ( Seconds, 60 )
VAR Hours =
    INT ( Minutes / 60 )
VAR RemMinutes =
    MOD ( Minutes, 60 )
RETURN
    TIME(Hours, RemMinutes, RemSeconds)
```

[image]

You can get rid of the "30.12.1899" prefix if you change the display format from *General Date* to *Long Time*.

[image]

Comment: Answer updated to return time data type instead of text.

Comment: Is there anything unclear with my answer?

Comment: Thank you so much! It calculates everything correct, but I have a problem when I choose the whole rest of IDs there calculating something strange. I don't know, perhaps it's something with my data connections or what...